# data.table merge() with NA in by column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to join two tables where the column that is joined on has some NA values such that when the NA is encountered the record is padded with NA's i.e.

Given:

```
> x = data.table(c(1,2,3,NA,5), c("a","b","c","d","e"))
> x
   V1 V2
1:  1  a
2:  2  b
3:  3  c
4: NA  d
5:  5  e

> y = data.table(c(NA,2,3,4,5), c("A","B","C","D","E"))
> y
   V1 V2
1: NA  A
2:  2  B
3:  3  C
4:  4  D
5:  5  E
```

I want my output to be:

```
> z = data.table(c(NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5),c("d",NA,"a","b","c",NA,"e"),c(NA,"A",NA,"B","C","D","E"))
> z
   V1 V2 V3
1: NA  d NA
2: NA NA  A
3:  1  a NA
4:  2  b  B
5:  3  c  C
6:  4 NA  D
7:  5  e  E
```

I thought `merge()` could be used to do this. But I can't get it to produce the output I expect:

```
> merge(x,y, by=c("V1"), all=TRUE)
   V1 V2.x V2.y
1: NA    d    A
2:  1    a   NA
3:  2    b    B
4:  3    c    C
5:  4   NA    D
6:  5    e    E
```

I really don't like that it merges based on the NA value as if it was a match, and when I do this in a larger table with several NA's, it seems to iterate over all possible combinations of column values for V1 and V2 given an NA key. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dataframe method of `merge` has a `incomparables`-argument, which the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) version of `merge` doesn't have.

So, using the dataframe method:

```
merge.data.frame(x, y, by = "V1", all = TRUE, incomparables = NA)
```

gives the intended result:

> ```
>   V1 V2.x V2.y
> 1  1    a <NA>
> 2  2    b    B
> 3  3    c    C
> 4  4 <NA>    D
> 5  5    e    E
> 6 NA    d <NA>
> 7 NA <NA>    A
> ```

---

<sub>NOTE: [According to this GitHub-issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2587), the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) developers are planning to include an `incomparables`-argument in `merge.data.table` in the future.</sub>

Comment: Solid answer. Thank you. Any idea for why data.table hasn't got this functionality?

Comment: @llevar the [tag:data.table] developer are aware of this and planning to include this functionality in the future [according to this GH-issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2587)

Comment: Thank you. Strange choice by them as this is standard OUTER JOIN behavior pretty much across the board.