# merge two data.tables with NAs in the by= indicator(s)

Tags: r, data.table

I want to merge two large data.tables but I have many NAs in the id vars. In reality, I have many id variables, all of which have `NAs` but my question becomes clear in this toy example:

```
library(data.table)


testdata_1 <- data.table(var_a = c("a", NA, NA, NA),
                         mergevar= c(1, 2, NA, NA))


testdata_2 <- data.table(var_b = c("b", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                         mergevar = c(1, 2, 3 , NA, NA))

merge(testdata_1, testdata_2, by = c("mergevar"))
```

Not only does this merge on `NA`, it even merges each `NA` in `x` with each `NA` in `y`. What is going on here? How can I tell `merge()` to ignore cases where the `by =` variable is `NA` in one of the data.tables? Does this just work by manually subsetting the inputs or is there a way to do this in merge? Here the manual solution:

```
merge(testdata_1[!is.na(mergevar)], testdata_2[!is.na(mergevar)], by = c("mergevar"))
```

However, is difficult with more than one id variable when they have `NAs` for different rows. Say id1 exists, then I want to merge on it even if id2 is na. This is already happening (see `mergevar1 = 4` below). But I do now want to merge on NA's alone. An example with two ids might also help:

```
testdata_3 <- data.table(var_a = c("a","b","c","d"),
                         mergevar1 = c(1,2, NA,4),
                         mergevar2 = c(1,2, NA,NA))


testdata_4 <- data.table(var_b = c("b",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                        mergevar1 = c(1,2,NA , NA,4),
                        mergevar2 = c(1,NA,3 , NA,NA))


merge(testdata_3, testdata_4, by = c("mergevar1", "mergevar2"))

   mergevar1 mergevar2 var_a var_b
1:        NA        NA     c  <NA>
2:         1         1     a     b
3:         4        NA     d  <NA>
```

Here, I'm worried about row 1 of the result. Edit: And about the fact that `mergevar1 = 2` doesn't lead to a merge.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [data.table merge() with NA in by column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255804/data-table-merge-with-na-in-by-column)

Comment: It does for the first example but incomparables "is only supported for merging on a single column". But it does answer my question in the sense that I now know that I have to do this manually for now. Maybe someone still comes up with a join solution or something like that so I'll leave it open?

Comment: For data.table this is an open issue, but there are probably workarounds

Comment: Just replace the NAs to a different variable (i.e. "missing")?